# How to use a repository not linked to an entity in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, symfony, repository, symfony4, repository-pattern

I have a custom repository returning raw data that wouldn't fit in an entity.

```php
namespace App\Repository;

class RevenuesRepository
{
    /**
     * @return array Raw data about revenues
     */
    public function getRevenuesRecap()
    {
        // ...
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I want to use it in a controller, but I can't use `$em->getRepository(...)` because this repository is not linked to an entity. How can I do that?

Comment: repositories can provide functions that return raw data. having an extra repository might provide some benefits still. also in symfony 4 and 5 you can just use dependency injection / auto-wiring to get a repository by adding it to the controller's __construct or action method arguments, which imho is *way cleaner* then using the container (which is frowned upon)

Comment: I don't want to create an empty entity just to make my repository works, is that possible? If so, how could I do that?

Comment: I can't tell what amount of proficiency you have, since I answered your question twice somewhat. The entity manager in doctrine ORM obviously handles entities. adding something unrelated to an entity is semantically wrong. requesting a repository from it, that is unrelated to an entity is semantically wrong. also, you have found a way to make it work, I added another way to make it work in my answer ... so I don't really understand what you try to achieve if it's not something that's semantically wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your standalone custom repository in a controller function, it should be absolutely sufficient to add it to either action method signature or constructor signature:

```
use App\Repository\RevenuesRepository;

class RevenuesController {

    private $revenuesRepository;

    // inject it in constructor
    public __construct(RevenuesRepository $revenuesRepository) {
        $this->revenuesRepository = $revenuesRepository;
    }

    // OR (!) inject it in action
    public function getRevenuesRecapAction(RevenuesRepository $revenuesRepository) {
        $recap = $revenuesRepository->getRevenuesRecap();

        $response->setContent(json_encode([
            'data' => $recap,
        ]));

        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

This way, when testing for example, it's clearly visible what the dependencies are and what you might have to mock or provide. Also, it provides your IDE with direct data for static analysis and code completion and more helpful information like method signatures.

This works due to auto-wiring. In symfony 4 and 5 repositories are by default services and thus can be auto-wired and injected quasi automatically.